# Get Session on current Page after session Time Out

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, oracle11g

If session was expire then after without going to any where(ex. login Page), how I get session on same page.

Please help me for that I have searching a lot for that but I am not able to find out.

Thnaks in advance,
Technoera Team Member

Comment: does this work, are you still looking for possible answers!

Answer (score 1):

You are just concerned about getting session stored value from lost session, definitely you can do that.
E.g. if you have `Session["user"] = "arindam"`, and session expires, you won't get that.

Solutions, on page load save Session["user"] in an input hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdn" runat="server"/>
document.getElementById("hdn") = "<%= Session["user"] %>";
```

, on postback if session is lost, then get that value from hdn variable, as Request.Form["hdn"].